# Vuetify 3 - Cannot Import Async Components

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, async-components

I know this isn't the best time to use vuetify 3 but, i did. Hoping everything goes well until i found out that a lot of components are still missing.

Now, I am having a problem importing a lazy component using defineAsyncComponent.
my DOM doesn't seem to recognize async components.
I don't know if it is a vuetify error but my project is made out of vuetify so I was suspecting it was the problem.

Below is my code in dashboardACtionsLayout.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex mb-3 mt-2">
      <add-customer-modal />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

components: {
  addCustomerModal: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
    import("@/components/customer/addCustomerModal.vue")
  );
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

and this is the error i am getting in my console:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use defineAsyncComponent like below.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex mb-3 mt-2">
      <add-customer-modal />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

const AddCustomerModal = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('@/components/customer/addCustomerModal.vue')
)

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

note:

The name of your component is addCustomerModal, while vue's recommendation is that the beginning of all words should be capitalized, like AddCustomerModal.

Comment: Ok now it's working. I have tried that syntax earlier. Except the capitalization. Now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: now i am having another error. When i register two components like this; const AddCustomerModal = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import("@/components/customer/addCustomerModal.vue")
);

const CustomersModal = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
  import("@/components/customer/customersModal.vue");
});

Answer (score 0):

It is now fixed as of @m kh answer. But when I try to register two components using this code; `

```
const AddCustomerModal = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import("@/components/customer/addCustomerModal.vue")
);

const CustomersModal = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
  import("@/components/customer/customersModal.vue");
});
```

` I will get an error like this [image]